# Does someone have a low level inplemenation of tensorflow's ConvLSTM2D

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, cnn, lstm

Right now I am using the ConvLSTM2D module of tensorflow and it works. But now I would like to feed an additional input between the convolutional stage and the lstm module. Therefore I would need a low-level implementation of this?

Does someone know, how to do that? can I do it with Conv2 and LSTM? But LSTM is takes no 2D input?

Thanks

Comment: You can reshape your Conv2 output, just to feed as an input to LSTM cell. Regarding second part you will definitely find lots of document online...

Comment: The problem with this is that the Lstm module is for 1D and not 2D. Basically I need a 2D Lstm module.

Comment: As I said above you can reshape your data accordingly. Also for better understanding of use case, please do share the example.